# What is the relationship between rank and solutions of a linear system with multiple columns?

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

We can determine whether or not a linear system $Ax = b$ has a unique solution or a solution at all based on the rank of the augmented matrix rank$(A|b)$ and the rank of the matrix rank$(A)$. (e.g.: [Linear system solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3066301/linear-system-solutions))

What happens in a more complex linear system where $b$ is replaced by $B$ which has multiple columns? For example:

Be $A \in K^{i,j}$ and $B \in K^{i,k}$ with $i,j,k \in \mathbb{N}$. When does the linear system $AX = B$ have at least one solution $\hat{X} \in K^{j,k}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X = (x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ and $B = (b_1,\ldots,b_k)$. Then $AX = B$ is equivalent to $Ax_n = b_n$ for all $n \in \{1,\ldots,k\}$. Now you can apply your theorem recursively to obtain that $AX = B$ has a solution if and only if $\mathrm{rank}(A|B) = \mathrm{rank}(A)$.

Comment: Okay, I get that for $Ax_n = b_n$ to have a solution, $\text{rank}(A|b_n)$ needs to be the same as $\text{rank}(A)$ and that this is the case for every $n$. However, how do I tie that together to arrive at your conclusion that it only has a solution if and only if $\text{rank}(A|B) = \text{rank}(A)$?

Comment: Let me formulate it a bit differently. If $AX = B$ has a solution, then clearly $\mathrm{rank}(A|B) = \mathrm{rank}(A)$ as you can write every column of $B$ as a linear combination of columns of $A$. Conversely, if $\mathrm{rank}(A|B) = \mathrm{rank}(A)$, then every column of $B$ can be written as a linear combination of columns of $A$, that is, $Ax_n = b_n$ has a solution for every $n$.

Comment: Okay, that helped a lot, thank you. Is the solution also only unique iff $\text{rank}(A) = \text{rank}(A|B) = j$?